# anchor tag with background image inside button redirects to the background href rather then the button Onclick Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a div with href and background image also i have the button with onclick also , but when i tried to click the button it does not redirects the button link , where as it redirects the background href link.

```
<div class="banner-container">
<div class="banner-box">
    <div class="banner-div">
        <div class="bannerheading">
            <p><span>The correct link should be&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: test">
            <button id="ngwr40hslzejpruyuvx" onclick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/')" data-gahref="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs newtab">Learn more</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
        <div class="banner-img" style="background-image:url('https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png');">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

with out hcnaging hte HTML can anyone able to help https://jsfiddle.net/uqbhcdn6/2/ , how to redirect the button click ?

Comment: link opens on both the button and the link

Comment: hi @Tik its not working on button , only the background href redirects

Comment: Why did you set pointer-events:none; to the content box, remove that everything will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add css `pointer-events: fill;` to the button...

```
<button style="pointer-events: fill;" id="ngwr40hslzejpruyuvx" onclick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/')" data-gahref="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs newtab">Learn more</button>
```

i edit your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syamsoul/a8e1kng7/1/) for your ease: https://jsfiddle.net/syamsoul/a8e1kng7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Remove **pointer-events:none** for .banner-div class.
The above property doesn't react to pointer events, hence the click/hover events couldn't be performed